# change top tabs font family in react-native-navigation (android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there any way to change top tabs font family in the `topTabs` or `appStyle` ? i used `tabFontFamily` but it change the font family in bottom bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pull Request #2342](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/2342) had solved my problem by using **topTabTextFontFamily** option

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
tabBarTextFontFamily: 'Avenir-Medium' //change the tab font family
```

from [Wix Doc](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/styling-the-tab-bar?id=style-object-format)